# Axure Checkbox Interactions, 3 Cases: None Checked, 1 Checked, or 2+ Checked?

Tags: tools, axure

I have a list of checkboxes, and I would like to tie them to a dynamic panel in a specific way:

- If no checkboxes are selected, display a Dynamic Panel's state 0.
- If only one (any) checkbox is selected, display a Dynamic Panel's state 1.
- If two or more (any) checkboxes are selected, display a Dynamic Panel's state 2.

Is there a way to define this in a case?

I'm guessing no as I don't see any way to group checkboxes into a collection.

However, I thought I'd toss this out there and see if someone with more experience knows of a method for achieving this result.

Comment: This question is better suited to StackOverflow, as it relates more to how to use a product than on any UX question.

Comment: It's possible, just make sure to use conditions and check the value of the checkboxes for each of these cases.

Comment: @JohnGB This would not be a good fit on Stack Overflow, there's no implementation to speak of. Speaking as a mod on StackOverflow myself, It would be quickly closed as non constructive.

Comment: Hi Charles. I'm afraid this isn't on topic for our site. Although Axure is used by UX professionals, questions about how to use it aren't suitable for here as they are not UX issues themselves.

Comment: No problem.  For future reference, where would be an appropriate place?

Comment: Also you might want to think about tightening up the FAQ.  Nowhere in there does it say that a question about UX tools should not be asked.

In fact, the FAQ as currently written encourages exactly the type of question I asked (which I actually consulted prior to asking this question).

According to the FAQ my question passes this test: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"

Just a friendly suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I spent nearly two hours to try in Axure, I found the way to do it, but just for research on this problem, if I was working on a project, I absolutely wouldn't spend so much time on this.

For better understanding, I used four panels - state0/1/2/3 to describe select none/1/2/3. I am glad that I can attach pictures now:). Any other questions please let me know.

However, I hope you solved this problem by adding notes :), since Axure is a simple and rapid prototype development tool, you cannot demand everything, or we can development product just by it. :)

[image: checkbox a]

[image: checkbox b]

[image: checkbox c]

Comment: This would work, a little complex though because if there are 8 checkboxes this needs to be repeated 8 times.

Comment: yeah, right. But try not to design so complex haha.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this. Use an extra dynamic panel, it will act as your "checker".

onLoad > hide "Checker"

Checker: onHide

- 3 cases checking (use conditions) all checkboxes for the scenarios you listed
- wait 50 ms
- show "checker

Checker: onShow

- hide "Checker:

I hope this makes sense. It is a very useful thing to learn how to make and this Checker pattern can be reused especially with forms. It is easily maintained and doesn't require the user to even interact with your form to trigger a change. The checker will automatically know what state the panel should be in.